# Change the color of bottom navigation bar item

Tags: android, colors, bottomnavigationview

I set the primary color as a certain type of orange and I can't understand why by default my bottom navigation bar takes white and not primary color as the color for the selected items, how to solve?

xml code for the bottom navigation bar

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
```

colors (the primary is some kind of orange)

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#fb8c00</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#c25e00</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">#ffbd45</color>
<color name="textOnPrimary">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
```

as you can see the item selected and the text are white while the primary color is orange
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following three tags to control the coloring of `Tabs` as well as Text shown in the Tabs in `BottomNavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

And it looks like this,

[image]

Unfortunately, I could've created Drawable to handle different states, but the itemIconTint takes only color as input and not Drawable. Still pretty close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: what is selector? also this does not work, I would like to have black color when the item is not selected (like the one on the screenshot) and the primary color (orange) when the item is selected instead of white

Comment: I'll check on my end and add the code in like an hour

Comment: I've edited my answer, and it works on my end. You just need to change the color values with what you want. I've purposefully kept those values so you know what each value does, don't forget to upvote and accept if it works for you

Comment: I want only the selected item to be orange and not white. what I want to achieve is this, https://ibb.co/hd3Bp6M in another application it was enough to change the primary color between colors and write the code I wrote in the post, now I can't understand why the selected item is white instead of orange (in this case I put the background with primary accent so that the selected item does not get confused with the white of the background)

Comment: I've edited my answer and brought results pretty close to what you wanted to achieve

Comment: sorry but this once again does not solve my problem. Only the selected item must be orange, the one with the text below, the others must be black.

Comment: that's what i said in the last sentence..itemIconTint only takes color as its parameter, if it took drawable, i could've added different colors for different states..but it is tint so wouldn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Step-1 Create drawable file under drawable folder and and add below code.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#82C341" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="#a9a9a9" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Step-2 Then use this drawable file like this.
       **Add these two lines.**
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/your_drawable_file_name"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/your_drawable_file_name"

**Full Code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/tab_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/your_drawable_file_name"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```